# I'm confused about threads and JSON

Tags: android, json

I am trying to make multiple text views for my data. But I am having trouble.
Also I would need to update my data every 2 seconds continuously, and a for loop didn't help.
Here is the JSON api URl https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

```
public class IsstatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String longitSt;
JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
TextView latitude;
TextView longitude;
String lat;
String longit;

JSONObject jobj = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.isstatus);
    latitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);
    new retrievedata().execute();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    return true;
}

class retrievedata extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    public String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        jobj =   jsonparser.makeHttpRequest("http://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544");
        // check your log for json response
        try {
            lat = "latitude: " + jobj.getString("latitude");
            longit = "longitude :" + jobj.getString("longitude");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return lat;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(String lat) {
  latitude.setText(lat);
  longit.setText(longitude);
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably need a timer that fires every 2 seconds. It should check if the AsyncTask is still running and cancel it, then fire a new one.

Having said that, don't use AsyncTask, look at Retrofit.

Comment: would Retrofit work with my URL?

Comment: https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544

Comment: Yes it should. 15 char